# SQL Count occurrences of non-unique column

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a SQL table looking something like this:

```
--------------------
|  id|         name|
--------------------
|   1|        Alice|
|   2|          Bob|
|   3|        Alice|
|   4|        Alice|
|   5|         Jeff|
| ...|          ...|
--------------------
```

Is it possible to formulate a query which returns a list of names and the number of times they occur? I've made a solution to this by querying all the rows, removing duplicates counting and then ordering; which works, but just looks messy. Can this be neatened up in a SQL query?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard SQL and should deliver your expected result:

```
select name, count(*)
from  tblName
group by name
order by name
```

If you want to order by the count in descending order, you can use:

```
select name, count(*)
from  tblName
group by name
order by 2 DESC
```

Comment: change the last line to `order by name DESC` if you want the result set in descending order.

Comment: Can it be ordered by the count, so I get Alice,3 Bob,1 Jeff,1 etc?

Comment: yep, `order by 2`